# Como passar e receber um parâmetro entre componentes angular

Tags: angular

Estava passando o parâmetro `Id` utilizando `Routes`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'sites', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'addSite', component: AddSiteComponent },
  { path: 'sites', component: ShowSitesComponent },
  { path: 'sites/editSite/:_id', component: EditSiteComponent }
];
```

Que ao passar o parâmetro `site._id`, ele supostamente vai para o componente `editSite`(posso ver ele no URL) com este parâmetro, porém não consigo receber o valor parâmetro para usar no outro componente.

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">
    <a routerLink="editSite/{{site._id}}" style="text-decoration: none; color: white" routerLinkActive="active">Editar</a>
</button>
```

O que eu deveria colocar para receber este `id`? ou qualquer outro parâmetro.

Comment: eu faço assim,  no init do component de edição: 
if (
            this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params &&
            this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id
        ) {
            const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para receber um parâmetro no componente use

```
const _id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params._id;
```

Não esquecer de colocar no **constructor**

```
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
```

Comment: tem como enviar o objeto completo? sem ser  só o id?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro Não é muito seguro enviares o objeto todo por um "GET", mas poderás por exemplo Encriptar para ficar mais pequeno e assim enviar tudo no parâmetro e depois no componente desessenciar.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro A melhor maneira de enviar um objeto inteiro enquanto mudas de páginas será usar Store, assim ao guardares os objetos numa store local do navegador do utilizador, poderás obter o objeto completo pelo ID

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigado

Comment: Para passar objetos ou valores complexos, sugiro que você utilize um Resolve, veja no link da documentação do Angular: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: Ou voce pode armazenar esse objeto em cache utilizando um servico compartilhado.